# How to align check box with label only using CSS

Tags: html, css, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use Azure Active Directory B2C for user registration on a web app. I need to add a few checkboxes which have long text labels. I can't seem to get the checkboxes to align with the labels as seen below:

[Checkboxes not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLQjH.png)

The problem is that I have no access the that code, at least not to my knowledge?

I know I can upload custom templates and perhaps use CSS to align the checkboxes and label?

The code is injected like this:

```html
<li class="CheckboxMultiSelect">
  <div class="attrEntry"><label id="extension_Purposeofuse_label" for="extension_Purposeofuse">Purpose of use</label>
    <div class="error itemLevel" role="alert"></div>
    
    <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_a" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_a_option" value="a">
<label id="a_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_a">a) an investigation into fraud, corruption or theft, provided that the South African Police Service or any other statutory enforcement agency conducts such an investigation;</label>
    
    <input
      id="extension_Purposeofuse_b" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_b_option" value="b">
      <label id="b_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_b"> b) fraud detection and fraud prevention services;</label>
      
      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_c" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_c_option"
        value="c">
        <label id="c_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_c"> c) considering a candidate for employment in a position that requires honesty in dealing with cash or finances;</label>
        
        <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_d" name="extension_Purposeofuse"
        type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_d_option" value="d">
        <label id="d_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_d"> d) an assessment of the debtors book 
of a business for the purposes of: • the sale of the business or debtors book of that business; or
• any other transaction that is dependent upon determining the value of the business or debtors book of that business;</label>
```

[Here is the link to the b2c sign in page](https://dataonelogindev.b2clogin.com/dataonelogindev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SignupAndSignIn&client_id=b61c5450-5a17-4c6e-8419-069040f12273&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdataone.powerappsportals.com%2Fsignin-AAD-B2C_1&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)

Click sign up and you will see the checkboxes

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: I have updated the link. Please click on "sign up" to see the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these codes.

### EDIT

```css
label {
  width:90%;
  display:inline-flex;
}

input {
  width:5%;
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<li class="CheckboxMultiSelect">
  <div class="attrEntry"><label id="extension_Purposeofuse_label" for="extension_Purposeofuse">Purpose of use</label>
    <div class="error itemLevel" role="alert"></div>
    
    <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_a" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_a_option" value="a">
<label id="a_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_a">a) an investigation into fraud, corruption or theft, provided that the South African Police Service or any other statutory enforcement agency conducts such an investigation;</label>
    
    <input
      id="extension_Purposeofuse_b" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_b_option" value="b">
      <label id="b_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_b"> b) fraud detection and fraud prevention services;</label>
      
      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_c" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_c_option"
        value="c">
        <label id="c_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_c"> c) considering a candidate for employment in a position that requires honesty in dealing with cash or finances;</label>
        
        <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_d" name="extension_Purposeofuse"
        type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_d_option" value="d">
        <label id="d_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_d"> d) an assessment of the debtors book 
of a business for the purposes of: • the sale of the business or debtors book of that business; or
• any other transaction that is dependent upon determining the value of the business or debtors book of that business;</label>
```

Comment: I can't change the html code. Its part of the azure ad b2c. I can create a custom template but the problem is that the code that asks for the email, phone, checkboxes, etc. is injected into the template so I cannot change it at all. Is there a way to do it only using CSS?

Comment: How is this? I'll update the answer if it works. https://codepen.io/flashbey/pen/xxEjdpq

Answer (score 0):

A modern approach is either the use of flexbox or CSS-Grid. Create 2 a wrapper of the checkboxes and labels. With `grid-template-columns: min-content auto;` you have the checkbox column only take as much space as needed and the label taking the remaining width available.

```css
.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="CheckboxMultiSelect">
  <div class="attrEntry">
    <label id="extension_Purposeofuse_label" for="extension_Purposeofuse">Purpose of use</label>
    <div class="error itemLevel" role="alert"></div>

    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">

      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_a" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_a_option" value="a">
      <label id="a_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_a">a) an investigation into fraud, corruption or theft, provided that the South African Police Service or any other statutory enforcement agency conducts such an investigation;</label>

      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_b" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_b_option" value="b">
      <label id="b_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_b"> b) fraud detection and fraud prevention services;</label>

      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_c" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_c_option" value="c">
      <label id="c_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_c"> c) considering a candidate for employment in a position that requires honesty in dealing with cash or finances;</label>

      <input id="extension_Purposeofuse_d" name="extension_Purposeofuse" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="extension_Purposeofuse_label extension_Purposeofuse_d_option" value="d">
      <label id="d_option" for="extension_Purposeofuse_d"> d) an assessment of the debtors book 
of a business for the purposes of: • the sale of the business or debtors book of that business; or
• any other transaction that is dependent upon determining the value of the business or debtors book of that business;    
      </label>

    </div>

  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I am unable to add the "checkbox-wrapper" div to the html. I cannot edit the html at all. Is there a way to do it only using css? The format of the html is as follows: